# could not checkin on facebook from my iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

Recently Publishing a Checkin object is deprecated in favor of creating an Open Graph story with a location attached. You can also create a Post with a location attached using the 'publish_steam' extended permission.
I have posted checkin from my application by posting a story on timeline with the place id and it was working fine two days ago but now I am getting this error response

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1e5d03e0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 1;
            "error_data" =             {
                kError = 1455002;
            };
            message = "(#1) An unknown error occurred";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1f98cfd0, state: FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended, loginHandler: 0x1f98d330, appID: 372278036211319, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy:
```

Do anyone have the fix of this issue?

Comment: Did you find a reason?  I have the same error now also

Comment: Might be completely offtopic, but the on-going bug on FB where people can't seem to post anything has the exact same error-number (1455002). If this isn't fixed already, you could try and mail them. Couldn't find the error anywhere else but here, perhaps it's an unknown bug?

Comment: Hi, I have the same error message (see post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529192/facebook-graph-api-can-post-on-me-feed-but-not-on-page-id-feed-error-14)