# Facebook graph API : can post on "me/feed" but not on "page_id/feed" (error : 1455002)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I guess the answer to this one is straightforward but I cannot find it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

**I. Use case**

The application (back-end in python / django) should write on a facebook page.

**II. Symptoms**

- When running the code below on "me/feed", the post is correctly inserted
- When running the code below on "PAGE_ID/feed", there is an exception (see below in section IV.)
- The scope of the authorisation is publish_stream, manage_pages
- Also, the user_token is from a user in the test domain

**III. Code**

```
## Getting the user_access_token is dealt with before

h = Http()    

data = dict(message="Hello", access_token=user_access_token['access_token'])

resp, content = h.request("https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed", "POST", urlencode(data))
```

**IV. Exception generated (using /PAGE_ID/feed)**

**resp** : Response: {'status': '400', 'content-length': '119', 'expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'www-authenticate': 
 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#1) An unknown error occurred"', 'x-fb-rev': '976458', 
 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-store', 'date': 'Tue, 22 Oct 2013 21:45:20 
 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8', 'x-fb-debug': 
 'HFItWh64ob+3hErv+rgYdFzHlRBVHP7Pg0Eg4hvqYlY='}

**content** str: {"error":{"message":"(#1) An unknown error occurred","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"error_data":
 {"kError":1455002}}}

Comment: Hi Hugues, not sure if you're still having this problem. I encountered the exact same error, and although I couldn't narrow down what was causing it, as soon as I tried to post from a Regular human account (instead of a test user) it worked fine with no change in the code whatsoever. It's worth mentioning I'm posting to a page the user is an admin of (with all the appropriate permissions), though the same was true of the test account. Hope that helps a little. Have a great one and good luck.

Comment: Hi Francisco, thanks a lot for your input. The application is still in the test domain hence I couldn't see yet if it would work in production. Based on your feedback, it is as I suspected a Facebook bug. Do you think we should register a bug at Facebook ?